# Refused to display X in a frame even though there are headers : ALLOW-FROM https://accounts.google.com/*

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jetty, same-origin-policy

I have an angular-js application that is hosted by jetty (i can host it by gulp serve)

It has an index.html and i want it to call `gapi` to connect the current user and ask him\her for oauth for permissions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>


</head>

<body ng-app="promptoWeb" ng-cloak layout="column" layout-fill="" style="height:100%">
```

However when i get `index.html` I see in the developer console this error:

> :3000/#!/:1 Refused to display
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=505822449425-e01arfrf92…res__%2Fam%3DkQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOUIXKgKDwlapCiIqRNkMcHmGTEjw'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:559 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=505822449425-e01arfrf92…res__%2Fam%3DkQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOUIXKgKDwlapCiIqRNkMcHmGTEjw net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
bx @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:559
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:570
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:568
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:551
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:101
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:97
VM2548:1 GET https://content-issuetracker.corp.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?pp=0&field…ds%5B%22methods%22%5D%2Cfields%5B%22batchPath%22%5D%2Cfields%5B%22id%22%5D 403 ()
(anonymous) @ VM2548:1
zu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:130
n @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:130
Cu @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:131
(anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:131
g @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:87
c @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:83
VM2548:1 GET https://content-issuetracker.corp.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?pp=0&field…ds%5B%22methods%22%5D%2Cfields%5B%22batchPath%22%5D%2Cfields%5B%22id%22%5D 403 ()
```

Why do i get this? as iJetty adds these headers:

`X-Frame-Options:ALLOW-FROM https://accounts.google.com/*`

Comment: *“Refused to display '`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`… in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.”*… There are no changes you can make to your Jetty code nor anywhere to overcome the fact that `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` sets 'X-Frame-Options: sameorigin'. That’s what the error message is telling you.